# How to set audio playbackrate in PhoneGap on Android?

Tags: html, audio, cordova

Has anyone been able to get audio playbackrate to work on Android? The Media Player seems to override/ignore the playbackrate property of an audio tag.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It seems playbackrate is not supported in any way.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358547/how-to-set-html5-video-speed-in-android