# Phonegap play (native) audio and change playback rate

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

Is there a way to hav native audio playback in phonegap application with ability to change playback rate?

It seems that oficial Media plugin doesn't support playback change.

HTML5 audio is not an option, it is flaw on mobile.

Comment: check [cordova media plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.media)

Comment: It does't support this as I've mentioned in OP.

Comment: That plugin will set playback rate for ios only afaik

Comment: Yes, it was my PR.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262884/how-to-set-audio-playbackrate-in-phonegap-on-android