# how to set html5 video speed in android

Tags: android, html, cordova, video

I should set video speed in android.
But playbackrate,defaultplaybackrate  is not working.

What should I do?

```
 var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
 video.defaultPlaybackRate = 2.0;             
 video.play();
 video.playbackRate = p_Speed;
```

- cordova 3.5
- android 4.2.2

Answer (score 2):

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=263654&q=playbackRate&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Doesn't look like there is an answer to this issue yet.  I also tried crosswalk since it allowed the opportunity to experience a fuller library and was built with chromium but unfortunately, https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk/topic/543325 - this does not seem to have a correction in there as well, I tested against crosswalk 1.3.0

As far as I could tell, the only answer is to take the video, use ffmpeg(or something similar) and create a iframes simulating the speed you want.